# ¿Cómo se puede eliminar las comillas de los elementos de una lista en Python?

Tags: python, string, lista

Trato de hacer un programa que consiste en obtener la cantidad de números pares e impares en un número. Para eso se me ocurrió "desfragmentar" el número en dígitos, separados entre sí en una lista. Sin embargo, el programa me da error. Lo más probable es que Python no pueda interpretar lo que esté en comillas, por lo que empecé a usar ".strip", que tampoco elimina las comillas.

```
x = input("Ingrese un numero: ")
print(list(x))
lista = list(x)
lista2 = []
j = 0
k = 0
while j < len(list(x)):
    lista[k] = lista[k].strip('"')
    lista2.append(lista[k].strip('"'))
    j += 1
    k += 1
print(lista2)
par = 0
impar = 0
i = 0
while i < len(list(x)):
    if lista2[i] % 2 == 0:
        par += 1
        i += 1
    elif lista2[i] % 2 != 0:
        impar += 1
        i += 1

print("La cantidad de números par son " + par + " y la cantidad de 
números impar son " + impar)
```

---

```
Ingrese un numero: 308489249
['3', '0', '8', '4', '8', '9', '2', '4', '9']
['3', '0', '8', '4', '8', '9', '2', '4', '9']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/gpep5.py", line 17, in <module>
    if lista2[i] % 2 == 0:
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

¿Qué podría hacer en este caso?

Comment: Bienvenido Cristobal c: Podrías poner tanto el código como lo que te muestra Python en la consola en forma de texto por favor? Aquí te dejo una lectura de la importancia de esto: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2869#2869

Comment: Creo que ya me hago una idea de lo que pasa, te haré una respuesta en cuanto edites tu pregunta como te dije en el comentario anterior.

Comment: Hola, edité la publicación según lo que me pediste jeje

Answer (score 1):

Tu error se debe a otra cosa. Pero para entender la causa del error primero dejame explicarte que es lo que hace tu código.

## Explicación

Primero que nada, el comando input devuelve lo que escribió el usuario en forma de cadena. Piensa en las cadenas como palabras, oraciones, texto en general. Por ejemplo "hola mundo. Soy Dante c:" es una cadena. Perdón si digo algo que ya sabías, es que cuando hago respuestas asumo ante la duda que el que pregunta requiere estas explicaciones.

Pero volviendo al tema, cuando se habla de programación NO es lo mismo el numero 123 que la cadena "123".

Cuando haces `lista = list(x)` lo que haces es separar esa cadena en cada "letra" que la forma. En caso de "123" se crea la lista `["1", "2", "3"]`.

Asumo que en este bloque de código:

```
while j < len(list(x)):
    lista[k] = lista[k].strip('"')
    lista2.append(lista[k].strip('"'))
    j += 1
    k += 1
```

estás intentando quitar las comillas a las que te refieres. Dejame decirte que esas comillas NO forman parte de cada item de la lista. Si no que así Python representa a las cadenas, rodeadas por comillas simples.
Esa parte del código por lo tanto es innecesaria.

Entonces pasamos a tu segundo bucle while, que es donde te da el error.

Recuerdas lo que dije antes de que la cadena "123" no es lo mismo que el numero 123? Pues aquí también aplica.
Cuando ejecutas esta linea `if lista2[i] % 2 == 0:` estás diciendole a Python "Hacé tal letra dividido 2 y decime el resto que te da".
Por ejemplo, si el usuario ingresó 123, y se procesa el primer item de la lista, le estás diciendo a Python "Hacé la letra 1 dividido 2 y decime el resto".
Como notarás, no se puede dividir una cadena o letra por un numero.

Si intentas dividir una cadena por algo, Python le da a ese intento un trato diferente al numerico, el cual quizá habrás visto como `"hola %s" % "mundo"`.
Pero no explicaré eso en esta respuesta, ya que me iría de tema.

## Solución

En base a esto, podemos aplicar estos principios y modificar tu código para que funcione.

```
x = input("Ingrese un numero: ")
print(list(x))
lista = list(x)

# Elimino este while ya que es innecesario.
"""
j = 0
k = 0
while j < len(list(x)):
    lista[k] = lista[k].strip('"')
    lista2.append(lista[k].strip('"'))
    j += 1
    k += 1
print(lista2)
"""

par = 0
impar = 0
i = 0

#Hice un cambio en este while ya que ahora lista2 no existe. En su lugar recorre los items de lista.
while i < len(list(x)):
    # Al hacer int(cadena), convierto la cadena en un entero (o sea un numero NO decimal).
    if int(lista[i]) % 2 == 0:
        par += 1
        i += 1
    elif int(lista[i]) % 2 != 0:
        impar += 1
        i += 1

# Aquí estás tratando de sumar una cadena con un número. Eso es imposible. Con str(numero) convierto el numero en cadena.
print("La cantidad de números par son " + str(par) + " y la cantidad de números impar son " + str(impar))
```

## Mejoras extra al código

Tu código puede ser mejorado y acortado. Aquí te dejo el código modificado con aclaraciones sobre cada cambio y posteriormente links para saber más sobre dichos temas.

```
x = input("Ingrese un numero: ")

par = 0
impar = 0

# Aquí en lugar de usar un while puedes usar un bucle for.
# El for recorre cada letra de la cadena x y guarda cada letra en la variable cifra.
# En tu caso podría decirse que recorre el numero y obtiene cada cifra.
for cifra in x:
    if int(cifra) % 2 == 0:
        par += 1
    # Aquí no hace falta que uses un elif, puedes usar un else, el cual ocurrirá si el if y todos los demás elifs dan falso.
    #elif int(lista[i]) % 2 != 0:
    else:
        impar += 1

# Aquí estás tratando de sumar una cadena con un número. Eso es imposible. Con str(numero) convierto el numero en cadena.
print("La cantidad de números par son " + str(par) + " y la cantidad de números impar son " + str(impar))
```

Links:

- Bucle for: https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-for.html
- Else: https://www.mclibre.org/consultar/python/lecciones/python-if-else.html

---

Cualquier cosa que no entiendas dime, aquí estamos para ayudar! c:

Comment: Muchas gracias por toda la explicación!